# Fuser cannot stat file - strange behavior

Tags: linux, bash, stat

1.Create file:

```
touch 1.txt
```

2.Loop

```
for i in {0..1000}; do fuser 1.txt;done
```

3.Watch ~50 failures:

```
...
Cannot stat file /proc/16927/fd/0: No such file or directory
Cannot stat file /proc/17821/fd/0: No such file or directory
Cannot stat file /proc/17823/fd/0: No such file or directory
...
```

4. Why such fails?

5.Additional information: local FS, ext3, stat always returns valid response, 'selinux' off

Comment: Processes dying while `fuser` is attempting to determine if they are the owner of the file? Watch `strace` on the `fuser` call to see?

Comment: Whichever ones had those pids when `fuser` noticed them but had stopped existing by the time it got to looking at their open file descriptors. If you look at `/proc` you'll see a directory for every running process (directories are pid numbers). The `fd` directory contains links from the `fd` number to the file/etc. that it refers to. When a process dies the `/proc/<pid>` directory goes away. This is just a guess by the way.

Comment: I cant see any PIDs here, only FDs. Shouldnt fuser get the actual FD for that particular file and not anything else? Isn't that whole idea of the fuser ?

Comment: A file doesn't have an fd. Processes do. They open files as a given fd number. I'm assuming that `fuser` walks the running processes and looks for open `fd`s that point to the file in question and that during that attempt some of the processes are dying during `fuser` inspecting them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `fuser` walks the running processes and looks for open `fd`s that point to the file in question and that during that attempt some of the processes are dying during `fuser` inspecting them. –  Etan Reisner